# hashing string to int by remainder

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I'm practicing hashing string to int, by length, first char, remainder, etc.
Currently, I'm working out "hashing by remainder" part. After the remainder hash function, I have to get a probability that is less than 1 ( p < 1). However, my remainder function result in p = 1. It says I have to thread the modulo through the loop that computes the sum. The total hash table size is 65536, and I have to modulo of 65413 which is smaller than table size. Please give an advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp>
using namespace std;

vector<int> hashes(65536);
vector<int> entry_size(65536);
ifstream file("words.txt");
string line;
boost::math::chi_squared c2d(65535.0);

void hash_by_remainder(){
    int counter = 0;
    while(file >> line){
            uint16_t  hashed = 0;
            for ( int i=0; i < line.size(); i++){
                    uint16_t s_value = line.at(i);
                    hashed = hashed + s_value;
                    hashed = hashed % 65413;
            }
            uint16_t hashed_value = hash<string>{}(line);
            hashes.at(hashed) = hashed_value;
            entry_size.at(hashed) += 1;
            counter++;
    }
    float expected = counter/65536;
    float c2 = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 65536; i++){
            c2 = c2 + (expected - entry_size[i])*(expected -  entry_size[i])/expected;
    }
    float p = boost::math::cdf(c2d,c2);
    cout << c2 << endl;
    cout << p << endl; //checking the probability
}
```

Comment: `counter / 65536` performs integer division, which truncates the result down to the whole number. Probably not what you want here.

Comment: Then, what should I change? counter / 65536 means that expected = Number of words / 65,536 for Pearson's X square test.

Comment: Try `counter / 65536.0`

Comment: I already tried it and c2 increased to 7.97156e+06, but p is still 1

Comment: I forgot most of my college statistics, but I do remember that cumulative distribution function (of any distribution) is supposed to asymptotically approach 1. So the fact that `boost::math::cdf(HugeNumber)` returns 1 is not surprising. Sadly, I don't remember enough to understand what you are trying to do with those probabilities, and so can't help you further, I'm afraid.

Comment: It says that 'probability 1' has too many collides, so I have to make it approach zero as much as I can(p<1). But thank you for your help.

Comment: my prof said that my inner loop is just doing basically a checksum, so I think I have to figure out another solution inside the inner loop that multiplies every character by a power of 256.